# RSS on the root of my domain

Tags: html, rss

I have added an RSS feed to my website but I can't get google readers and others to pick it up from just my root domain (www.example.com) they need the full address to the rss feed.  How can I get them to pick up my feed without my users needing to add the full RSS feed address?

I have added the meta tag below but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Your default document (i.e. the one you see on example.com) should have something like this inside the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="RSS" href="/feeds/question/1037523">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the head of your index page:

```
<link href="/myRssOutputFile.php" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a link in the head section of the page

```
<link href="/path/to/feed" title="Feed Title" type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery.
Be sure to use an absolute path instead of a relative path. Some poorly-designed readers and parsers don't normalize the relative path.